# Left to rigt animation effect ontouch not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I have made an application in android,I made two activites in that and ontouch event i want a swipe effect in that my code is as below but its not working,My code is as below,Please help me for it:

**Effect.java**

```
package com.Effects.pageeffects;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.FeatureInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class EffectsActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_effects);




    }

      @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(EffectsActivity.this, Page2Activity.class));

            // Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_rigth, R.anim.rigth_to_left);
            return true;

        }

}
```

Comment: have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6970908/1276374 ?

Comment: yep...i want is that When one swipe an activity next activity should be opened..!

Comment: @MocialovBoris-yep mann but i w=exactly don't now where to put it..in onCreate or.better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_rigth, R.anim.rigth_to_left); in the onCreate() method of Page2Activity after setContentView() method.

Comment: i have edited code as per you suggested and code also updated in question,But still not working..!

Comment: Whats the problem? Whats not working? Can you plz elaborate? Cause I did the same thing and it was working well.

Comment: @jatin-Dear i implement code as you suggested but onswiping on screen next activity should come which is not coming..getting?

Comment: First try it with a single button click event to check whether its working the way u want. And also place some logs to check r u getting into the onTouch() method?

Comment: Add return false from onTouch() method.

Comment: add log into onTouch method. Check on touch method is invoked or not?

Comment: thing is dat ..that code is working well in OnClick event and same thing i can't do in onTouch event????

Comment: I've got why its not working on onTouch. You have to set onTouchListener on the parent view of R.layout.activity_effects layout. like ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_relative_bg)).setOnTouchListener(EffectsActivity.this);

Answer (score -1):

You start your activity before override animations.