# Android’s overridePendingTransition and singleInstance

Tags: android, animation, transition, single-instance

I am stuck on an issue with overridePendingTransition not working after changing an activity’s launchMode to ‘singleInstance’. I’d love to hear your inputs on it

I am working on an app to navigate through a deck of cards. To keep things simple, let’s assume the App contains two activities **card_deck** and **card**. Tapping anywhere on the **card_deck** activity opens a **card** activity. You could then swipe left or right on the **card** activity to open the next/previous card from the deck. I have a neat enter and exit animation that occurs on swiping through **card**.

Here is how the android activity stack would look

[image]

As you have guessed by now, there are too many activities of type **card**.

I changed the launchMode of card activity from standard to singleInstace (I had yet another adMob related reason to go the singleInstance route). Now when I call the following code snippet, the animation no longer occurs.

```
from Card.class

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Card.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim);
```

I think the animation is suppressed as there will only be one activity of type card and it's onCreate will not be called (‘cos of making it single instance). I have also tried calling the overridePendingTransition() on onNewIntent()/onResume()  but it did not help.

In a nutshell, how could I display enter & exit animation when calling startActivity(activity, A.class) from A.class when ‘A’ has a launchMode of singleTop/singleInstance

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope... Ended up using Android's Baked in Viewpager.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i just decided to go back to "singleTop" and sort out the issues i was having properly. I think because "singleInstance" is on its own process the animation is basically forced to be like a switching application animation.

Comment: Did you try to call `overridePendingTransition()` in `onNewIntent()`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633543/overridependingtransition-does-not-work-when-flag-activity-reorder-to-front-is-u