# Android switch animation between singleInstance activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

Is it possible to have animation when switching between activities which were already started as "singleInstance" before?

Cause when using the transitions, it is animating only on fresh start and finish.

EDIT:
Ok, seems like it's not possible. Wasted my time on this.
There's another question concerting this and he gave up as well: [Android’s overridePendingTransition and singleInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895730/android-s-overridependingtransition-and-singleinstance)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [overridePendingTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I did. This is doing the animations only on fresh start and finish.

Comment: You can use "singleTop" then.  I think because "singleInstance" is on its own process, the animation is basically forced to be like a switching application animation.

Comment: With singleTop it is finishing the instance. I need the instance to be persistent as long as possible and therefore I'm using singleInstance.