# Shared Element Transition when reopening existing Activity in stack Reorder To Front

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have an Activity A from there I open Activity B, and pass the shared element to it. It animates the transition fine, but when I go back to Activity A and then go to Activity B again which is still in the stack using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

The shared element transition is not run.

With regular animations you call overridePendingTransition() in onNewIntent for the animations to run. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327091

I tried calling startPostponedEnterTransition() in there but nothing happened.

This is my code to allow for transitions

```
void allowWindowTransitions(){
Window w = getWindow();
w.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
```

Code to start activity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sharedElement, "profile");

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

I have tried messing around with setSharedElementReturnTransition & setSharedElementReenterTransition but nothing happened.

Is there a way trigger shared element transition manually to get around this.

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: If anyone has been stuck in this situation, I could really use some insights.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about Shared element transitions but you can override 
 onNewIntent method to apply animations when activity comes in foreground.

`@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent: ");
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_enter_from_right, R.anim.transition_exit_to_left);
    }`
Hope this helps!