# startActivity create new instance each time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nav

I have navView and a link on it to another activity each time I click that link 
it creates a new instance of the activity.

if the user click the link 3 times it creates 3 different instances.

I want to create only one instance at the first time and then reopen

```
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Photos.class);
Videos.this.startActivity(photosIntent);
```

Comment: declare launch mode for the activity as singleInstance in manifest. `<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />`

Comment: @Chithra Please don't suggest special launch modes to solve this problem! That's not the way to do it. Special launch modes cause more problems than they solve and most developers have no idea how this works.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent multiple instances from being created, you can do this:

```
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Photos.class);
photosIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
Videos.this.startActivity(photosIntent);
```

This will reuse an existing instance of `Photos` if that `Activity` is currently on top of the stack (ie: visible on screen).

If you have multiple activities, and you want to ensure that you only ever create a single instance of each one, you can do this:

```
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Photos.class);
photosIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
Videos.this.startActivity(photosIntent);
```

This will bring any existing instance of `Photos` to the top of the stack (ie: visible on screen), even if it is not already on top.

NOTE: Do NOT use the special launch modes `singleInstance` or `singleTask` as others have suggested. These will not help you and they perform special magic which will likely have you tearing your hair out later. You can specify `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for these activities if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can check instance for null. If it is null create new, otherwise open old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Photos.class);
photosIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(photosIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Android works. Activities have lifecycles and once you start an Activity a new instance will be created every time. Same as it will be destroyed once you no longer use it (go to another activity, close app, etc.)

try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your Android manifest for your activity and see if it works.

Comment: you mean override pending transition does not get triggered?

Comment: @Mostafa Try calling `overridePendingTransition()` in `onNewIntent()` see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633543/overridependingtransition-does-not-work-when-flag-activity-reorder-to-front-is-u)

Answer (score 0):

create a class variable like `private Intent photosIntent;`

replace this:

`Intent photosIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Photos.class);`

with:

`if(photosIntent == null){
    photosIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Photos.class);
}`

this should work fine

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `android:launchMode` with one of these:

- `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
- `android:launchMode="singleTop"`
- `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Here the usage sample:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="activity name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="">
```

Please be aware the above choices have different characteristic. I think that `singleTask` is the more suitable for you.

This article: [Understand Android Activity's launchMode: standard, singleTop, singleTask and singleInstance](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) explained their characteristics in details.

Comment: I used singleInstance works fine but I lost my sliding animation

as i added custom animation in styles.xml 

    <style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right </item>
        <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left </item>
</style>

Comment: Use of launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask` should rarely be necessary, unless you are building a HOME-screen replacement. Under normal circumstances you do not need these launch modes! Also, setting `taskAffinity` like this will create separate tasks for each `Activity`, which is certainly not what OP wants nor what the user expects. This is the wrong approach to solving this problem.